# Time synchronisation advices for requests in JS

Tags: javascript, time, request, synchronization

I need to send multiple requests to a server. But my headers are dynamic and depend on the result of the previous request.

I use fetch to send my request, which is asynchronous. for exemple:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

function server_time() {fetch("myserver/time", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));}
  
  console.log(server_time)
```

So In this example result is displayed to the console whenever I call FetchTime(). Ok, this is fine. But, this result in my specific application is the server time. I need then to insert it in another Header.

I also need to check the time before each request.

Right now I can't get the result out of my function FetchTime because it is asynchronous and the rest of my code will be executed before. I tried to use async/await. But still, end up with the same result.

Is there a way to execute the rest of my code only after the previous example or should I try with XMLHttpRequest which is synchronous?

Comment: Just continue the async chain by adding another `.then()` containing the next function to execute. Async/await is just syntax sugar for the same thing. And try to never set a xmlhttprequest back to synchronous, the entire point is to be async so we can do stuff while we wait for the server to respond.

Comment: Thank you, is there another way ? Because in that case, the async chain will continue at least half of my program and evry line will start with .then().

Comment: You can reference function names. So just define the functions of the chain separately and then write the logic at the bottom. Bit like: `const f1 = function(){ ... }; const f2 = function(){ ... }; fetch().then(f1).then(f2).catch(handleError);`. Or use async/await to get a synchronous code feeling. But I always advice people to start off with `.then()` and only switch to async/await once they understand it.

Comment: Ok, in your example can fonction 1 use fetch(). if it can, then how I use a value from f1 in f2? let say f1 is my server_time() funtion from my code instead of log result i want to give this result to f2.

Comment: I might have something, fetch() is a promise so if I put my request in a variable I should be able to chain link .then()